filtering list of vectors for entries that contain specific character
I have a list of string vectors that I want to filter for a function:
for(i in 1:length(strophlist)){
  strophlist[[i]] |> as.vector() |> context(open="(", close=")") -> melislist[[i]]
}

I tried running this as lapply, but whenever I do, I get the error "argument of length 0". I'm pretty sure this is because of the vectors that don't match the context criteria, so I wanna get rid of them.
The problem is, whenever I try to use something I found, usually like this:
strophlist[grep("^\\(.*", strophlist)]
Filter(function(x) all("^\\(.*" %in% x), strophlist)

I just get "named list()" or "list()" when I get rid of the names.
Can anyone help me?
strophlist <- list(`aus-tiefer-not-1535` = structure(c("2b", "4e", "4b", "4cc", 
"4b", "4g", "4a", "4b", "8r", "8b", "4cc", "4dd", "4cc", "4a", 
"(4g", "4f)", "4e", "2b", "4e", "4b", "4cc", "4b", "4g", "4a", 
"4b", "8r", "8b", "4cc", "4dd", "4cc", "4a", "(4g", "4f)", "4e", 
"8r", "8a", "4g", "4cc", "4b", "8a", "(4dd", "8cc)", "4b", "4a", 
"8r", "8cc", "4b", "4cc", "4dd", "4g", "8Lb", "8Jcc", "4a", "4g", 
"8r", "8g", "4cc", "4b", "4a", "4e", "(4g", "4f)", "1e"), visible = TRUE), 
    `Christ-lag-in-todesbanden-1524` = structure(c("2a", "4g", 
    "4a", "4cc", "4dd", "(4cc", "4b)", "4a", "4r", "4a", "4f", 
    "4g", "4a", "8Lg", "8Jf", "4e", "2d", "2a", "4g", "4a", "4cc", 
    "4dd", "(4cc", "4b)", "4a", "4r", "4a", "4f", "4g", "4a", 
    "8Lg", "8Jf", "4e", "2d", "4r", "4d", "4f", "4g", "4f", "4g", 
    "4a", "8r", "8a", "4dd", "4cc", "(4dd", "4ee)", "4cc", "4b", 
    "4a", "8r", "4a", "4cc", "4a", "4cc", "4g", "(8Lf", "8Jd", 
    "4e)", "4d", "4a", "8Lg", "8Jf", "4e", "1d"), visible = TRUE), 
    `ein-feste-burg-1535` = structure(c("2r", "4r", "4ff", "2ff", 
    "2ff", "2cc", "4dd", "(2ff", "4ee)", "2dd", "2cc", "4r", 
    "4ff", "2ee", "2dd", "2cc", "4dd", "(2b-", "4a", "2g)", "2f", 
    "2r", "4r", "4ff", "2ff", "2ff", "2cc", "4dd", "(2ff", "4ee)", 
    "2dd", "2cc", "4r", "4ff", "2ee", "2dd", "2cc", "4dd", "(2b-", 
    "4a", "2g)", "2f", "4r", "4f", "(4.a", "8b-", "4cc)", "(2dd", 
    "2cc)", "4b", "2cc", "2f", "2cc", "2dd", "2ee", "2ff", "2r", 
    "2ee", "2ff", "2ee", "2dd", "2cc", "2dd", "2dd", "4cc", "2dd", 
    "4cc", "2a", "4r", "4ff", "2ee", "2dd", "2cc", "4dd", "(2b", 
    "4a", "2g)", "0;f"), visible = TRUE), `Erschienen-ist-der-herrlich-tag-1560` = structure(c("4d", 
    "4d", "4d", "2a", "4b", "(4.cc", "8b)", "4a", "2g", "4a", 
    "2b", "4cc", "2dd", "4a", "(4.cc", "16Lb", "16Ja)", "4b", 
    "2a", "4b", "2cc", "4a", "2g", "4f", "(4.a", "8g)", "4f", 
    "2g", "4g", "2cc", "4dd", "2ee", "4dd", "2cc", "4gg", "2ee", 
    "4dd", "(2cc", "2dd)", "4b", "2a"), visible = TRUE), `es-ist-das-heil-uns-kommen-her-1524` = structure(c("4r", 
    "8r", "8dd", "4dd", "4dd", "4dd", "4ff", "4ee", "4dd", "4cc", 
    "8r", "8dd", "4b", "4g", "4b", "4cc", "(4dd", "4ee)", "4dd", 
    "4r", "8r", "8dd", "4dd", "4dd", "4dd", "4ff", "4ee", "4dd", 
    "4cc", "8r", "8dd", "4b", "4g", "4b", "4cc", "(4dd", "4ee)", 
    "4dd", "8r", "8dd", "4.gg", "8.ff", "4ee", "4dd", "4gg", 
    "4ee", "4dd", "8r", "8dd", "4.gg", "8cc", "4dd", "4g", "4b", 
    "4dd", "4b", "8r", "8g", "4a", "4cc", "4b", "4a", "(4e", 
    "4a)", "1;g"), visible = TRUE), `lobt-gott-ihr-christen-alle-gleich-1554` = structure(c("2r", 
    "4r", "4f", "4cc", "4cc", "4cc", "4cc", "4ee", "8Lcc", "8Jb-", 
    "4a", "4a", "4b-", "4cc", "4dd", "4dd", "2cc", "4r", "4cc", 
    "4cc", "4cc", "4cc", "4a", "4cc", "8Lb-", "8Ja", "4g", "4cc", 
    "4a", "8Lg", "8Jf", "4g", "4g", "2f", "2a", "2cc", "8Lb-", 
    "8Ja", "4g", "4g", "1f"), visible = TRUE), `Nun-komm-der-heiden-heiland-1524` = structure(c("4g", 
    "4g", "4f", "4b-", "8aL", "8gJ", "4a", "2g", "4g", "4b-", 
    "4.cc", "8b-", "4cc", "4dd", "2b-", "4b-", "4cc", "4dd", 
    "4b-", "4cc", "8Lb-", "8Ja", "2g", "4g", "4g", "4f", "4b-", 
    "8La", "8Jg", "4a", "0g"), visible = TRUE), `nun-lob-mein-seel-den-herrn-1530` = structure(c("2r", 
    "2r", "2g", "1b-", "2a", "1g", "2f", "(1b-", "2cc)", "1dd", 
    "2dd", "1dd", "2dd", "1dd", "2cc", "1b-", "2a", "1b-", "2r", 
    "2r", "2g", "1b-", "2a", "1g", "2f", "(1b-", "2cc)", "1dd", 
    "2dd", "1dd", "2dd", "1dd", "2cc", "1b-", "2a", "1b-", "2r", 
    "2r", "2b-", "1b-", "2dd", "1cc", "2dd", "(2b-", "1a)", "1g", 
    "2g", "1cc", "2cc", "(1cc", "2a", "2b-)", "1g", "1f", "2r", 
    "2r", "2f", "1b-", "2b-", "1cc", "2cc", "1dd", "1b-", "2b-", 
    "1ee", "2ee", "1dd", "2dd", "1cc", "2r", "2r", "2cc", "1dd", 
    "2dd", "1ee-", "2ee", "1ff", "1b-", "2dd", "1cc", "2f", "2a", 
    "1g", "1f", "2r", "2f", "1b-", "2b-", "1a", "2g", "1cc", 
    "1cc", "2dd", "1ee-", "2dd", "(2.b-", "4a", "4b-", "4cc)", 
    "1cc", "0b-"), visible = TRUE), `vom-himmel-hoch-da-komm-1539` = structure(c("4r", 
    "8r", "8f", "4cc", "4cc", "4dd", "4cc", "4a", "8Lb-", "8Jg", 
    "8r", "8f", "4cc", "4cc", "4cc", "8aL", "8Jb-", "8Lcc", "16b-", 
    "16Ja", "4g", "4f", "8r", "8f", "4f", "4g", "4a", "4a", "4f", 
    "4g", "4a", "8r", "8f", "4cc", "4cc", "4cc", "8La", "8Jb-", 
    "8Lcc", "16b-", "16Ja", "4g", "1f"), visible = TRUE), `wach-auf-deutsches-land-16jhd` = structure(c("1f", 
    "2a", "2b-", "2cc", "2cc", "2dd", "2dd", "1cc", "2r", "2cc", 
    "2dd", "2ee", "2ff", "2ff", "(2ee", "4dd", "4cc", "1ee)", 
    "1cc", "1f", "2a", "2b-", "2cc", "2cc", "2dd", "2dd", "1cc", 
    "2r", "2cc", "2dd", "2ee", "2ff", "2ff", "(2ee", "4dd", "4cc", 
    "1ee)", "1cc", "2r", "2cc", "1ff", "1cc", "1.ff", "2ee", 
    "(2.dd", "4cc", "2b-)", "2b-", "1a", "2r", "2a", "1cc", "2cc", 
    "1dd", "2cc", "2dd", "2ee", "1ff", "2r", "2ff", "1ff", "2cc", 
    "2dd", "2a", "(2.cc", "4b-", "2a", "4g", "4f", "1g)", "0f"
    ), visible = TRUE))


Update
If you would like to subset strophlist to such elements which include the pattern at least once, you might try
Filter(\(x) any(grepl("^\\(.*", x)), strophlist)


Thank you a lot, but this seems to only give me the exact substrings out of the vectors. What I need is actually the entire vectors that contain that substring, a subset of the list so to speak. Sorry if this was not clear enough.
What would be the proper way to go about this?

Unfortunately, I'm running into a different problem with this one. When I enter, I get the error of "invalid regular expression '(4g', reason 'Missing ') ' ' ". Other regex-expression or strings don't work either.

Should work now

Yes, it works! Thank you very much :)
